# Qulatrics loop and merge with multi levels

Tags: qualtrics

I'm working with a survey in which participants will see a random subset (50 out of 100) items based on specific criteria. In the loop and merge, these 50 (based on displayed choices) have two fields field1 and field2. Additionally, I have a separate, constant set of 50 items. My goal is to pair these constant items (like a Field3) with the initially displayed 50 items. However, I cannot add this field 3 as there will be 100 items in the loop and merge but only of the 50 secondary items can be paired with the selected choices.

An ideal scenario would be if I could loop through in two ways: 1. for the displayed choices (Field 1 and Field 2) and another exclusively for cycling through the constant 50 items.

I am not sure the best way to approach this please let me know if you have any suggestions/ solutions.